# ng-repeat towice in one table's <tr> conflict

Tags: angularjs

I have the following table that needs ng-repeat for two different column. I have tried the new method of ng-repeat-start/ng-repeat-end in vain:
Note: I have two different data providers with two different connections. I am forced to use this method since I don't have full control to edit the controllers or merge them also the controllers are part of two different APIs.

```
<table ng-switch-default>
    <tbody >
    <tr ng-repeat="name in names" ng-repeat="a in glamors">
    <td>{{a.glamor}}</td>
    <td>{{name.first}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What is the best method to use multi ng-repeat?

Comment: what kind of output you are looking for?

Comment: you can add two add both arrays of objects to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: You can merge this two object in controller, and then process merget object in one ng-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say your objects are:

```
$scope.names = [
    {first:'Fahad', last:"Khan"},
    {first:'Fahad2', last:"Khan2"},
    {first:'Fahad3', last:"Khan3"}
];
$scope.glamors = [
    {glamor:'glamour1'},
    {glamor:'glamour2'},
    {glamor:'glamour3'}
];
```

merge glamor with name:

```
var count = $scope.names.length;
for (var i=0; i<count; i++) {
    $scope.names[i].glamor=$scope.glamors[i].glamor;
}
```

Here is your all in one object:

> console.log($scope.names);

Use it as:

```
<table>
    <tbody >
    <tr ng-repeat="name in names">
    <td>{{name.glamor}}</td>
    <td>{{name.first}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hzxNa/295/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a bad pratice to use ng-repeat 2 times on the same structure, as one might overwrite what another is doing.

I would suggesting to create service that will parse both names and glamors into one object and then send it to your controller to display in a view.

Comment: Well I have two different data providers with two different connections. I am forced to use this method

Comment: Well, you can import those 2 providers and glue their values.

Answer (score -1):

Do you not just want to nest one inside the other? Something like:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="n in names">
        <td>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="a in glamors">
                    <td>{{a.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{n.name}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Do your styling correctly and you can't really tell they are separate tables.

Failing that, if a single table is a requirement, you are going to have to merge the data, as you mentioned in one of the other comments, you are getting your data from two sources, this isn't a problem, the solution would be something like:

```
var a = $http.get("NAMES");
var b = $http.get("GLAMORS");

// Using the promise library, you can have it wait for completion of multiple requests
$q.all([a, b]).then(function(results) {
    var names = results[0].data;
    var glamors = results[1].data;
    var output = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < glamors.length; j++) {
            output.push({ name: names[i], glamor: glamors[j] });
        }
    }

    $scope.data = output;
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xb779fjg/

Comment: your first method of styling will not work since it is associated with filters. I will try the sec method..

Comment: Not sure why using a filter would pose a problem for either option, but I can't answer something that isn't present. Either way, here is a fiddle with both options: http://jsfiddle.net/xb779fjg/